# How many valid 6 character passwords are there if it must contain at least two lowercase-letters, at least one digit and contains no repeated digits?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm going through this and getting tripped up as letters can repeat but digits can't.  My thoughts are:

1. Total number of 6 digit passwords = 36^6
2. Total number of passwords with only numbers = 10^6
3. Total number of passwords with only letters = 26 =^6
4. Total number of passwords with 1 letter = 10^5 + 26
5. Total number of passwords with repeating digits = ?

Then we'd have to subtract all of the invalid sets of passwords from the set of all passwords accounting for inclusion-exclusion?

**Edit**

Updated solution as per comments:

($26^5. {6 \choose 1} . 10 $) + ($26^4. {6 \choose 2} . 10 . 9$) + ($26^3. {6 \choose 3} . 10 . 9 . 8$) + ($26^2. {6 \choose 4} . 10 . 9 . 8. 7$)

Comment: Using $L$ for letters and $D$ for digits, why not just add valid passwords with $5L,1D,\; \;4L,2D,\;\; 3L,3D,\;\; 2L,4D$

Comment: @trueblueanil interesting so something like:


5L1D = (26^5 + 10^1)
4L2D = (26^4 + 10*9)
... etc?

But then I suppose we have to account for different orders i.e. aaa23 != a23aa

So for 5L1D it would be (26^5 + ${6 \choose 1}$ x 10^1)

Comment: and then 4L2D it would be (26^4 + ${6 \choose 2}$ x 10 x 9)

Is that the right idea?

Comment: Not $+,\;\;\times$, eg $26^4\cdot\binom62\cdot10\cdot9$

Comment: @mranonymous101 is capital letters allowed such as $A,B,..$. Moreover , do you know generating functions

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @Bulbasaur good question. In this case it's lower case letters only. I'm not familiar with generating functions but after a quick google it seems like that would allow me to express this same idea with more concise syntax. Thanks.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks!