# How many valid 6-character long passwords are there if it must contain at least one digit, at least 2 lowercase letters and no repeated digits?

Tags: combinatorics

How many valid passwords are there for a 6-character long password with lowercase letters or digits. Each password must contain at least two lowercase letters, at least one digit, and contains no repeated digits.

I would like to know if I am going about this correctly so far and how to handle no repeated digits. My steps, thus far:

1. Total Number of Passwords=36^6
2. Number of passwords with no letters=10^6

I believe I am supposed to use the subtraction approach but I am stuck here. I'd appreciate being guided to the right approach

---

Comment: 2. is wrong.  $10^6$ includes $999999$ for example.  The number of passwords with no letters would be $\binom{10}{6}$ (using the no repeated digits constraint).

Comment: Additive seems easier to me.  Choose N letters = $26^N$.  Then choose $6-N$ digits = $\binom{10} {6-N}$.  Then choose where the $6-N$ digits should go.  $\binom{6} {6-N}$.

Comment: What does the (10 6) notation mean? haven't seen it before... I just started combinatorics class last week, so please bear with me :)

Comment: $\binom nr = \frac {n!}{(n-r)!r!}$ is the number of combinations of $r$ distinct objects chosen from $n$. The  mathjax for this symbol is \binom{n}{r}

Comment: cool thanks @WW1

Comment: To use mathjax, sandwich the math between \$ signs. If you sandwich `26^N\binom{10}{6-N}` it looks like $26^N\binom{10}{6-N}$

Comment: Thanks @WW1 are there any docs for the use of mathjax? I'd like to explore further

Comment: Asked twice before: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4184130/how-many-valid-pass-words-are-there and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4175157/how-many-valid-6-character-passwords-are-there-if-it-must-contain-at-least-two-l

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: cheers guys, thanks